# How to use pycrate to encode Attach Request NAS messages

Tags: python

I tried to use pycrate to encapsulate the attach request in the LTE NAS message, but it was always unsuccessful. The place where I analyzed the error was the two IEs ESContainer and MSNetCap. The two IEs, ESMContainer and MSNetCap, have been packaged separately, but I don't know how to assign them to the attach request.

System ubuntu 18.04 IDE: pycharm python 3.6 pycrate0.4

input value:

```py
        Msg = EMMAttachRequest()
        Msg.set_val({'EMMHeader': [0, 7, 65]})
        Msg.set_val({'NAS_KSI': [[0, 7]]})
        Msg.set_val({'EPSAttachType': [2]})
        Msg['EPSID'].set_IE(
            val={'type': 1, 'ident': '1' + decode_bcd(b'\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10')})
        Msg['UENetCap'].set_val([4,
                                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                                  0, 0, 0,
                                  1, 1, 0,
                                  0,
                                  0, 0,
                                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                  0, 0, 0,
                                  0, 0,
                                  b'']])
        PDNConnectivityRequest = ESMPDNConnectivityRequest()
        PDNConnectivityRequest['ESMHeader'].set_val([0, 2, 1, 208])
        PDNConnectivityRequest['PDNType'].set_val([3])
        PDNConnectivityRequest['RequestType'].set_val([1])
        PDNConnectivityRequest['ProtConfig'].set_trans(False)
        PDNConnectivityRequest['ProtConfig'].set_val([39, 38, [1, 0, 0, [
            [32801, 16, [1, 1, 16, [[129, 6, b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'], [131, 6, b'\x00\x00\x00\x00']]]], [3, 0, b''],
            [10, 0, b''], [2, 0, b''], [12, 0, b''], [1, 0, b''], [13, 0, b'']]]])
        # Msg['ESMContainer'].set_val(vals={'V': PDNConnectivityRequest.to_bytes()})
        Msg['DRXParam'].set_trans(False)
        Msg['DRXParam'].set_val([92, [32, 0, 0, 0]])
        Msg['MSNetCap'].set_trans(False)
        Msg['MSNetCap'].set_val(
            {'T': 49, 'V':  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]})
        Msg['TMSIStatus'].set_trans(False)
        Msg['TMSIStatus'].set_val([9, [0, 0]])
        Msg['MSCm2'].set_trans(False)
        Msg['MSCm2'].set_val([17, 3, [0, 2, 1, 0, 7, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
        Msg['MSCm3'].set_trans(False)
        Msg['MSCm3'].set_val([32, 9,
                              [0, ['110', [0, 0, 0, 0], 1, 4], ['0'], ['0'], 0, 0, ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'],
                               ['1', 4], ['1', 1], 1, 0, 0, ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], 0, 1, ['0'], ['0'], '0', 0, 0, 0,
                               ['0'],
                               '0', 1, 0, ['0'], 1, ['0'], ['0'], 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
        Msg['SuppCodecs'].set_trans(False)
        Msg['SuppCodecs'].set_val([64, 8, [[4, 2, b'`\x00'], [0, 2, b'\x1f\x00']]])
        Msg['VoiceDomPref'].set_trans(False)
        Msg['VoiceDomPref'].set_val([93, 1, [0, 0, 0]])
        # print(Msg.show())
        return Msg.to_bytes()
```

success value:

```
### EMMAttachRequest ###
 ### EMMHeader ###
  <SecHdr : 0 (No security)>
  <ProtDisc : 7 (EMM)>
  <Type : 65 (Attach request)>
 ### NAS_KSI ###
  ### NAS_KSI ###
   <TSC : 0 ( native security context)>
   <Value : 7 (no key available)>
 ### EPSAttachType ###
  <V : 2 (combined EPS / IMSI attach)>
 ### EPSID ###
  <L : 8>
  ### EPSID ###
   <Digit1 : 0x1>
   <Odd : 1>
   <Type : 1 (IMSI)>
   <Digits : 0x01100000000010>
 ### UENetCap ###
  <L : 4>
  ### UENetCap ###
   <EEA0 : 1>
   <EEA1_128 : 1>
   <EEA2_128 : 1>
   <EEA3_128 : 1>
   <EEA4 : 0>
   <EEA5 : 0>
   <EEA6 : 0>
   <EEA7 : 0>
   <EIA0 : 1>
   <EIA1_128 : 1>
   <EIA2_128 : 1>
   <EIA3_128 : 1>
   <EIA4 : 0>
   <EIA5 : 0>
   <EIA6 : 0>
   <EIA7 : 0>
   <UEA0 : 1>
   <UEA1 : 1>
   <UEA2 : 0>
   <UEA3 : 0>
   <UEA4 : 0>
   <UEA5 : 0>
   <UEA6 : 0>
   <UEA7 : 0>
   <UCS2 : 1>
   <UIA1 : 1>
   <UIA2 : 0>
   <UIA3 : 0>
   <UIA4 : 0>
   <UIA5 : 0>00
   <UIA6 : 0>
   <UIA7 : 0>
 ### ESMContainer ###
  <L : 44>
  ### ESMPDNConnectivityRequest ###
   ### ESMHeader ###
    <EPSBearerId : 0>
    <ProtDisc : 2>
    <PTI : 1>
    <Type : 208 (PDN connectivity request)>
   ### PDNType ###
    <V : 3 (IPv4v6)>
   ### RequestType ###
    <V : 1 (Initial request)>
   ### ProtConfig ###
    <T : 39>
    <L : 38>
    ### ProtConfig ###
     <Ext : 1>
     <spare : 0>
     <Prot : 0 (PPP with IP PDP)>
     ### Config ###
      ### ProtConfigElt ###
       <ID : 32801 (IPCP)>
       <Len : 16>
       ### Cont ###
        <Code : 1 (Configure-Request)>
        <Id : 1>
        <Len : 16>
        ### Data ###
         ### NCPOpt ###
          <Type : 129 (Primary DNS Server Address)>
          <Len : 6>
          <Data : 0x00000000>
         ### NCPOpt ###
          <Type : 131 (Secondary DNS Server Address)>
          <Len : 6>
          <Data : 0x00000000>
      ### ProtConfigElt ###
       <ID : 3 (DNS Server IPv6 Address Request)>
       <Len : 0>
       <Cont : 0x>
      ### ProtConfigElt ###
       <ID : 10 (IP address allocation via NAS signalling)>
       <Len : 0>
       <Cont : 0x>
      ### ProtConfigElt ###
       <ID : 2 (IM CN Subsystem Signaling Flag)>
       <Len : 0>
       <Cont : 0x>
      ### ProtConfigElt ###
       <ID : 12 (P-CSCF IPv4 Address)>
       <Len : 0>
       <Cont : 0x>
      ### ProtConfigElt ###
       <ID : 1 (P-CSCF IPv6 Address Request)>
       <Len : 0>
       <Cont : 0x>
      ### ProtConfigElt ###
       <ID : 13 (DNS server IPv4 address request)>
       <Len : 0>
       <Cont : 0x>
 ### DRXParam ###
  <T : 92>
  ### DRXParam ###
   <SPLIT_PG_CYCLE_CODE : 32>
   <DRXCycleLen : 0 (DRX not specified by the MS)>
   <SPLITonCCCH : 0>
   <NonDRXTimer : 0 (no non-DRX mode after transfer state)>
 ### MSNetCap ###
  <T : 49>
  <L : 3>
  <ms_network_capability_value_part (CSN1List): [
   <(CSN1Ref): <gea1_bits (CSN1Bit): 1>>
   <sm_capabilities_via_dedicated_channels (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <sm_capabilities_via_gprs_channels (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <ucs2_support (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <ss_screening_indicator (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <solsa_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <revision_level_indicator (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <pfc_feature_mode (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <(CSN1Ref): <extended_gea_bits (CSN1List): [
    <gea_2 (CSN1Bit): 1>
    <gea_3 (CSN1Bit): 1>
    <gea_4 (CSN1Bit): 0>
    <gea_5 (CSN1Bit): 0>
    <gea_6 (CSN1Bit): 0>
    <gea_7 (CSN1Bit): 0>]>>
   <lcs_va_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <ps_inter_rat_ho_from_geran_to_utran_iu_mode_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <ps_inter_rat_ho_from_geran_to_e_utran_s1_mode_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <emm_combined_procedures_capability (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <isr_support (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <srvcc_to_geran_utran_capability (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <epc_capability (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <nf_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <geran_network_sharing_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>]>
 ### TMSIStatus ###
  <T : 9>
  ### TMSIStatus ###
   <spare : 0>
   <Flag : 0 (no valid TMSI available)>
 ### MSCm2 ###
  <T : 17>
  <L : 3>
  ### MSCm2 ###
   <spare : 0>
   <RevLevel : 2 (MS supporting R99 or later)>
   <EarlyCmCap : 1>
   <NoA51 : 0>
   <RFClass : 7>
   <spare : 0>
   <PSCap : 1>
   <SSScreeningCap : 1 (capability of handling of ellipsis notation and phase 2 error handling)>
   <MTSMSCap : 1>
   <VBSNotifCap : 0>
   <VGCSNotifCap : 0>
   <FCFreqCap : 0>
   <MSCm3Cap : 1>
   <spare : 0>
   <LCSVACap : 0>
   <UCS2 : 0>
   <SoLSACap : 0>
   <CMServPrompt : 1>
   <A53 : 1>
   <A52 : 0>
 ### MSCm3 ###
  <T : 32>
  <L : 9>
  <classmark_3_value_part (CSN1List): [
   <(CSN1Ref): <spare_bit (CSN1Bit): 0>>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 110 (multiband_supported) : [
    <(CSN1Ref): <a5_bits (CSN1List): [
     <a5_7 (CSN1Bit): 0>
     <a5_6 (CSN1Bit): 0>
     <a5_5 (CSN1Bit): 0>
     <a5_4 (CSN1Bit): 0>]>>
    <associated_radio_capability_2 (CSN1Bit): 1>
    <associated_radio_capability_1 (CSN1Bit): 4>]}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <ucs2_treatment (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <extended_measurement_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 1 : [
    <gsm_850_associated_radio_capability (CSN1Bit): 4>]}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 1 : [
    <gsm_1900_associated_radio_capability (CSN1Bit): 1>]}>
   <umts_fdd_radio_access_technology_capability (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <umts_3_84_mcps_tdd_radio_access_technology_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <cdma_2000_radio_access_technology_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <umts_1_28_mcps_tdd_radio_access_technology_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <geran_feature_package_1 (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Val): 0>
   <geran_feature_package_2 (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <gmsk_multislot_power_profile (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <_8_psk_multislot_power_profile (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Val): 0>
   <downlink_advanced_receiver_performance (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <dtm_enhancements_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <repeated_acch_capability (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <ciphering_mode_setting_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <additional_positioning_capabilities (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <e_utra_fdd_support (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <e_utra_tdd_support (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <e_utra_measurement_and_reporting_support (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <priority_based_reselection_support (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <utra_csg_cells_reporting (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <vamos_level (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <tighter_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <selective_ciphering_of_downlink_sacch (CSN1Bit): 0>]>
 ### SuppCodecs ###
  <T : 64>
  <L : 8>
  ### SuppCodecList ###
   ### SuppCodec ###
    <SysID : 4>
    <BMLen : 2>
    <CodecBM : 0b0110000000000000>
   ### SuppCodec ###
    <SysID : 0>
    <BMLen : 2>
    <CodecBM : 0b0001111100000000>
 ### VoiceDomPref ###
  <T : 93>
  <L : 1>
  ### VoiceDomPref ###
   <spare : 0>
   <UEUsage : 0 (Voice centric)>
   <VoiceDomPref : 0 (CS Voice only)>
```

my output value

```py
charpy(b'\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\\ \x001\x03\xe5`<\x90\x11\x03WX\x86 \t`\x14\x00R0 \x02C\xc0@\x08\x04\x02`\x00\x00\x02\x1f\x00]\x01\x00')
EMMAttachRequest, _dec_unk_ie: unknown Type4TLV IE, T: 0x0, V: 0x
charpy(b'\x00\x00\x00\\ \x001\x03\xe5`<\x90\x11\x03WX\x86 \t`\x14\x00R0 \x02C\xc0@\x08\x04\x02`\x00\x00\x02\x1f\x00]\x01\x00')
EMMAttachRequest, _dec_unk_ie: unknown Type4TLV IE, T: 0x3, V: 0x
charpy(b'\x00\\ \x001\x03\xe5`<\x90\x11\x03WX\x86 \t`\x14\x00R0 \x02C\xc0@\x08\x04\x02`\x00\x00\x02\x1f\x00]\x01\x00')
EMMAttachRequest, _dec_unk_ie: unknown Type4TLV IE, T: 0x0, V: 0x
### EMMAttachRequest ###
 ### EMMHeader ###
  <SecHdr : 0 (No security)>
  <ProtDisc : 7 (EMM)>
  <Type : 65 (Attach request)>
 ### NAS_KSI ###
  ### NAS_KSI ###
   <TSC : 0 ( native security context)>
   <Value : 7 (no key available)>
 ### EPSAttachType ###
  <V : 2 (combined EPS / IMSI attach)>
 ### EPSID ###
  <L : 8>
  ### EPSID ###
   <Digit1 : 0x1>
   <Odd : 1>
   <Type : 1 (IMSI)>
   <Digits : 0x01100000000010>
 ### UENetCap ###
  <L : 4>
  ### UENetCap ###
   <EEA0 : 1>
   <EEA1_128 : 1>
   <EEA2_128 : 1>
   <EEA3_128 : 1>
   <EEA4 : 0>
   <EEA5 : 0>
   <EEA6 : 0>
   <EEA7 : 0>
   <EIA0 : 1>
   <EIA1_128 : 1>
   <EIA2_128 : 1>
   <EIA3_128 : 1>
   <EIA4 : 0>
   <EIA5 : 0>
   <EIA6 : 0>
   <EIA7 : 0>
   <UEA0 : 1>
   <UEA1 : 1>
   <UEA2 : 0>
   <UEA3 : 0>
   <UEA4 : 0>
   <UEA5 : 0>
   <UEA6 : 0>
   <UEA7 : 0>
   <UCS2 : 1>
   <UIA1 : 1>
   <UIA2 : 0>
   <UIA3 : 0>
   <UIA4 : 0>
   <UIA5 : 0>
   <UIA6 : 0>
   <UIA7 : 0>
 ### ESMContainer ###
  <L : 0>
  <V : 0x>
 ### DRXParam ###
  <T : 92>
  ### DRXParam ###
   <SPLIT_PG_CYCLE_CODE : 32>
   <DRXCycleLen : 0 (DRX not specified by the MS)>
   <SPLITonCCCH : 0>
   <NonDRXTimer : 0 (no non-DRX mode after transfer state)>
 ### MSNetCap ###
  <T : 49>
  <L : 3>
  <ms_network_capability_value_part (CSN1List): [
   <(CSN1Ref): <gea1_bits (CSN1Bit): 1>>
   <sm_capabilities_via_dedicated_channels (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <sm_capabilities_via_gprs_channels (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <ucs2_support (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <ss_screening_indicator (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <solsa_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <revision_level_indicator (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <pfc_feature_mode (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <(CSN1Ref): <extended_gea_bits (CSN1List): [
    <gea_2 (CSN1Bit): 1>
    <gea_3 (CSN1Bit): 1>
    <gea_4 (CSN1Bit): 0>
    <gea_5 (CSN1Bit): 0>
    <gea_6 (CSN1Bit): 0>
    <gea_7 (CSN1Bit): 0>]>>
   <lcs_va_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <ps_inter_rat_ho_from_geran_to_utran_iu_mode_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <ps_inter_rat_ho_from_geran_to_e_utran_s1_mode_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <emm_combined_procedures_capability (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <isr_support (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <srvcc_to_geran_utran_capability (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <epc_capability (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <nf_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <geran_network_sharing_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>]>
 ### TMSIStatus ###
  <T : 9>
  ### TMSIStatus ###
   <spare : 0>
   <Flag : 0 (no valid TMSI available)>
 ### MSCm2 ###
  <T : 17>
  <L : 3>
  ### MSCm2 ###
   <spare : 0>
   <RevLevel : 2 (MS supporting R99 or later)>
   <EarlyCmCap : 1>
   <NoA51 : 0>
   <RFClass : 7>
   <spare : 0>
   <PSCap : 1>
   <SSScreeningCap : 1 (capability of handling of ellipsis notation and phase 2 error handling)>
   <MTSMSCap : 1>
   <VBSNotifCap : 0>
   <VGCSNotifCap : 0>
   <FCFreqCap : 0>
   <MSCm3Cap : 1>
   <spare : 0>
   <LCSVACap : 0>
   <UCS2 : 0>
   <SoLSACap : 0>
   <CMServPrompt : 1>
   <A53 : 1>
   <A52 : 0>
 ### MSCm3 ###
  <T : 32>
  <L : 9>
  <classmark_3_value_part (CSN1List): [
   <(CSN1Ref): <spare_bit (CSN1Bit): 0>>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 110 (multiband_supported) : [
    <(CSN1Ref): <a5_bits (CSN1List): [
     <a5_7 (CSN1Bit): 0>
     <a5_6 (CSN1Bit): 0>
     <a5_5 (CSN1Bit): 0>
     <a5_4 (CSN1Bit): 0>]>>
    <associated_radio_capability_2 (CSN1Bit): 1>
    <associated_radio_capability_1 (CSN1Bit): 4>]}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <ucs2_treatment (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <extended_measurement_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 1 : [
    <gsm_850_associated_radio_capability (CSN1Bit): 4>]}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 1 : [
    <gsm_1900_associated_radio_capability (CSN1Bit): 1>]}>
   <umts_fdd_radio_access_technology_capability (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <umts_3_84_mcps_tdd_radio_access_technology_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <cdma_2000_radio_access_technology_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <umts_1_28_mcps_tdd_radio_access_technology_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <geran_feature_package_1 (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Val): 0>
   <geran_feature_package_2 (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <gmsk_multislot_power_profile (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <_8_psk_multislot_power_profile (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Val): 0>
   <downlink_advanced_receiver_performance (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <dtm_enhancements_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <repeated_acch_capability (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <(CSN1Alt): { 0 : []}>
   <ciphering_mode_setting_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <additional_positioning_capabilities (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <e_utra_fdd_support (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <e_utra_tdd_support (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <e_utra_measurement_and_reporting_support (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <priority_based_reselection_support (CSN1Bit): 1>
   <utra_csg_cells_reporting (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <vamos_level (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <tighter_capability (CSN1Bit): 0>
   <selective_ciphering_of_downlink_sacch (CSN1Bit): 0>]>
 ### SuppCodecs ###
  <T : 64>
  <L : 8>
  ### SuppCodecList ###
   ### SuppCodec ###
    <SysID : 4>
    <BMLen : 2>
    <CodecBM : 0b0110000000000000>
   ### SuppCodec ###
    <SysID : 0>
    <BMLen : 2>
    <CodecBM : 0b0001111100000000>
 ### VoiceDomPref ###
  <T : 93>
  <L : 1>
  ### VoiceDomPref ###
   <spare : 0>
   <UEUsage : 0 (Voice centric)>
   <VoiceDomPref : 0 (CS Voice only)>
```

Comment: This is the parsing value of the success data.07417208190110000000001004F0F0C0C0002C0201D03127268080211001010010810600000000830600000000000300000A00000200000C00000100000D005C20003103E5603C90110357588620096014005230200243C040080402600000021F005D0100